# Comparing the datatype of an inner class attributes to its corresponding datatype

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I just want to know the attributes datatype of a class has inner class objects while iterating.

Find the code mentioned below.

```
class myClass1: NSObject {
    var name:String?
    var id:Int32?
}

class myClass2:NSObject {
    var sessionId:String?
    var classObj:[myClass1]?
    var item:Int?
}

let mirroredObject = Mirror(reflecting: myClass2())
var dictionary = [String:Any]()

for(index,attr) in mirroredObject.children.enumerated() {
    if let property_name = attr.label {
        let submirroredObj = Mirror(reflecting: property_name)
        dictionary["\(property_name)"] = type(of: (attr.value)) as Any?
    }
}

for (index,item) in dictionary.enumerated() {
    print(item.value)
}
```

In the above code it will display the list of attributes of a classObject. here I don't know how to compare the listed attributes of a class.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the type of the property:

```
attr.value.dynamicType
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick Response.                                    (atta.value).dynamicType no more,  In Swift 3.0 it will be replaced by "type(of:(atta.value))."    Actually I got the response as "Optional<String>
Optional<Array<myClass1>>
Optional<Int>"  I just want to compare those values with datatype .